# Configure XRDP session to display Session Manager

Tags: xorg, session-management, xrdp

I'm trying to setup a light environment on my Ubuntu server. I'm pretty new to things like session manager, x org etc.

I've installed LXDE and XFCE4, I've some session manager like SDDM, SLIM, etc.

I use XRDP to connect from my Ubuntu desktop. My server is headless, no screen, running in a VM.

When I connect through RDP, I use xorg session, and it launch a XFCE4 session.

How can I launch a session manager instead ?
Or can I set a default session to connect ?

Also I tried to install LXQT but when I launch it in terminal it says "no qt platform plugin could be initialized, maybe because there's no screen?

I really hope to get lxqt running on this server.m and access with RDP.

Thanks a lot.